# Redisson library used with Redis throws RedisConnectionException

Tags: redisson

Redisson (https://github.com/redisson/redisson) throws org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException when i'm trying to update some redisson variable and the underlying redis is down. So, why does it not mention in the code: something like 
throws org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException for all the methods ?

I wanted to use this library because it lets me set timeouts for individual entries of a hashmap. I'm going to use it in my production applications. Is it safe to use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, why does it not mention in the code: something like throws org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException for all the methods ?

It's state of design

> Is it safe to use it ?

Sure you can. Many companies across the world trust to Redisson. See `used by` section on project page.